# Selenium WebDriver get Current frame before switch

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a custom action to find elements, by switching in the certain iFrame.
It uses the following native action:
`driver.switchTo().frame(requested_frame)`
Currently I am switching back to the default content every-time before switch to the exact iframe.

Now I need to improve it's performance by following scnario:

- Check the current content/frame
- if `requested_frame=currentFrame` then No need to switch
- if `requested_frame=null` then switch to default (if `currentFrame=default` then again no need to switch)
- if `requested_frame!=null && requested_frame!=currentFrame` then switch to default, and switch to `requested_frame` frame.

So all I need now is to get the Current Frame. Is there any way I can get it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As the exact answer for my own question **"Selenium WebDriver get Current frame"** I found the following way to do it.

```
JavascriptExecutor jsExecutor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
String currentFrame = jsExecutor.executeScript("return self.name");
```

But in here, the JavascriptExecutor execute the command every time to get the current frame.
So if I consider the performance, I would like to choose #[Saurabh Gaur](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3193455/saurabh-gaur)'s answer as the best answer .
I hope my answer would be helpful to someone else :-)

---

### **Adding later**

I Just did a small test, with my current version, with a global variable and with the js command help.

[*Time collected (ms) on perfoming actions in 4 different elements in 2 nested iframes 1000 times. (4000 find element actions in total)* ]

```
|          | Switch everytime | Global variable | JS command | 
|----------|------------------|-----------------|------------| 
|          | 2023             | 1950            | 2911       | 
|          | 1902             | 2091            | 2992       | 
|          | 2014             | 1974            | 3020       | 
|          | 1934             | 1931            | 3097       | 
|          | 1997             | 1965            | 3180       | 
|----------|------------------|-----------------|------------|
| Average  | 1974             | 1982.2          | 3040       |
```

So the current performance with my "Switching default everytime" is not bad at all :D

Comment: I tried implementing this in WebDriverJS but it returns a pending promise no matter what I do.

Comment: JavascriptExecutor jsExecutor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
  String frame = (String) jsExecutor.executeScript("return self.location.toString()");

Answer (score 5):

You need to implement as below approach :-

```
String frame = 'your frame';
String currentFrame = null;
// make this currentFrame as global

if ((null != frame) && (!"".equals(frame))) {
        if (!frame.equals(currentFrame)) {
            switchToFrame(frame);
            currentFrame = frame;
        }
    } else {
        currentFrame = "";
        webDriver.switchTo().defaultContent();
    }

public void switchToFrame(String frame) {
    webDriver.switchTo().defaultContent();
    webDriver.switchTo().frame(frame);
}
```

Hope it will handle your all conditions..:)